# Unity Launcher is Showing up in Gnome Flashback Session, Bug or Design?

Tags: unity, 17.04, gnome-flashback

Just as the questions states.....I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04 and had previously had Gnome Session installed, but since I have updated Unity Launcher shows up in my Gnome session. Is this by design or something I need to fix?

EDIT: This behavior goes away after reboot and signing into Gnome Flashback first but reappears after logging into unity/logging out/signing back into Gnome.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour.  I think you should file a bug report in the Ubuntu bug tracking system.